# What does "Ref* pSender" do in Call Back function?

Tags: c++, event-handling, cocos2d-x

So I notice the `Ref* pSender` appears in many call back function and I wonder in the below code:

1) What is it?

2) Where does it come from? I didn't define it outside of the lambda.

3) What are some usages of it?

```
mFamilyTV = MenuItemImage::create("en_block5.png", "en_block5_hover.png",
        [=](Ref* pSender) {
        auto jump = JumpBy::create(1.0, Vec2(0, 0), 100, 1);
        mFamilyTV->runAction(jump);
    });
```

Your attention and help is very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) What is it?

It is the item that triggered the lambda function. In your case, your `mFamilyTV`.

> 2) Where does it come from? I didn't define it outside of the lambda.

The unit *executing* the lambda later will pass it.

> 3) What are some usages of it?

It enables you to attach the same function to multiple instances and still know which instance triggered it. Lets say you had a lambda to set the background to red on a button click. You could attach it to 15 buttons and if you programmed it right (in this case, changing the color of `pSender` instead of named buttons ), it works for all 15. And any amount of others, even if you don't even know them at compile time and don't have variable names for them in your program.

Comment: Then could I save the `pSender` for later use (i.e attach to other buttons in your example) in another lambda while creating another button or it will be released/deleted as soon as the above lambda ends ? If yes, could you please teach me how to do it? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: You should not use it outside of the lambda expression, because there is no guarantee what will happen to it. If you think you need it, you may want to ask another question because you should not need to use this outside of the lambda expression. That's what your actual variable mFamilyTV is for.

Answer (score 1):

In your case `Ref* pSender` is `mFamilyTV`. It is a sender, which triggered menu item click. `Ref` is a very basic class to support autorelease functionality. You can cast it back to MenuItemImage.

Here you can check inheritance diagram of `MenuItemImage`:

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.0alpha0/d1/d30/classcocos2d_1_1_menu_item_image.html